# PHP and Python on amazon ec2

Tags: php, python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon ec2 obunto micro instance. I have wrote a php code which executes a python code and echo the result which is a simple string. When I execute it on obuntu terminal it shows the result perfectly, but when I access it through the browser it doesn't show anything.
And I have no idea why. Actually it cannot execute the python script.

$tmp = exec('/usr/bin/python /var/www/similarity.py employee/unemployed/ waiter');

If anyonw can help me I would really appreciate it.
PS: I am using a mac book pro and when I use the same codes in the localhost of my computer everything works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of "scratching my head", I finally figured it out.

First of all you will need to figure out current user who is executing the php. You can either check out php.info file or use

```
$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
print $processUser['name'];
```

This will give you the user who is executing the code. In my case it was `apache` rather than `www-data` (I shouldn't have assumed so in first place).

After that you will need to edit the `sudoers` file `(etc/sudoers)`

Add the lines over there.

You can use @Janith's code, if you want to be specific.

```
apache ALL=NOPASSWD:/var/www/similarity.py
apache ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/python
```

or you can simply add

```
apache ALL=(ALL)        NOPASSWD:ALL
```

(You probably should just specify the path).

Then execute the script through php.

Answer (score 0):

This is permission problem to access python file. When you running it through server python script access as apache user(most probably www-data). So apache user doesn't having privilege to execute the python file.

What you can do it is run this command as sudo and add all necessary access to apache user(www-data) in  /etc/sudoers file as below sample.

```
 www-data ALL=NOPASSWD:/var/www/similarity.py
 www-data ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/python
```

This is just the sample, you should change this line as according to your environment.