# How can I serve PHP files from a Python EC2 instance?

Tags: php, python, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a Python Elastic Beanstalk environment and have some PHP files I need to serve. How can I do this?

I'm attempting something like

```
@application.route("/")
def test():
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('static', filename='redirect/index.php'))
```

but get the PHP file as text.

---

The [answer to the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17770327/656912) here isn't quite what I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python SimpleHTTPServer with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235876/python-simplehttpserver-with-php)

Comment: @Tal: I don't see anything relevant there.

Comment: it explains how to run PHP on Python and why you get the source file instead of serving it

Comment: @Tal: How can I serve PHP files from a Python EC2 instance? The linked answer doesn't get me any closer.